# Why my electron app not run in any windows?There must be a logical explanation for the failure

Tags: electron, electron.net

When I run the app on Windows, I get a spinning loader for 1-2 sec. and then nothing happens. The app, when running properly, shows an icon in the task bar and opens a browser window for the user to login.

I'm using electron-log, but nothing is printed to the logs. It seems like the app is dying before it can start. I'm looking through Event Viewer and don't see anything obvious. I feel like I'm missing something and don't have a great way to understand what's happening.

Any suggestions on where to look on Windows 10 to understand why an electron app isn't doing anything?

Comment: What actual version of windows 10 are you attempting to run it on? I have an electron application that doesn't work on Lenovo usb stick computers, using a really old version of Windows 10. On older versions of windows, like Windows 8, the application just fails to open any kind of window and force-closes.

Comment: windows 10 enterprise 1511 my version.

Comment: Why old windows may fail to run? Are there services running the application

Comment: I haven't been able to find a reason for it to fail honestly. 1511 is relatively old, in fact, I believe it's already been "retired" by Microsoft.

Comment: I am now downloading the update and knowing that the application may be for more than one user it is reasonable to force them to update their copies. There must be a logical explanation for the failure.

Comment: I agree, "Update your system" is not a good "fix" to the problem, I wish I had more answers for you.

Comment: try running sysinternals procmon, it will at least show you everything that its doing. Maybe you will see clues there (missing files for example) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: This sounds like a silent death of some node module. Do you use any npm modules which use a binary *.node (e.g. sqlite3)?

Comment: The question is badly phrased but this is a real problem, in my case all Electron-based apps (VSCode, Teams, Skype, Joplin) simply fail to open on Windows 10 some time after the last reboot.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing all the operations it became clear to me that the error lay in the application and had to be installed
  sqlserver exspress on the current machine because the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

**A little attention and inquiry always negates obstacles**